# Infinitest : No such method when using temporary folder

Tags: eclipse, junit, temporary-directory, infinitest

I have a problem with Infinitest:

I'm working with a junit temporary folder :

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder testFolder = new TemporaryFolder();
```

then I'm trying in the test method to create a temp sub-folder in this temp folder, and work with it :

```
@Test
public void shouldCheckFolders() throws InputDataException, IOException {
    File subFolder = testFolder.newFolder("subFolder");

    // ... anything for the test
}
```

When running the test using maven Clean install, no problem, I have a success. When using Eclipse : Run As -> Junit test, no problem : everything is green.

But Infinitest has an error :

```
NoSuchMethodError (org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder.newFolder(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/io/File;) in LeTest.shouldCheckFolders
```

Any idea ? 
is it possible to work with temporary folder and InfiniTest ?

I'm using Spring Tool Suite, based on Eclipse Mars 4.5.0 with Infinitest 5.1 and Junit 4.10.

Comment: It's maybe an incompatibility between Infinitest and Junit versions. Try to upgrade/downgrade JUnit version.